Connection is not getting established with Azure ADLS using apache arrow fc++ library
For connecting with Azure ADLS storage, I did the following using apache arrow c++ library 16.1 version:

Set secretkey using AzureOptions::ConfigureAccountKeyCredential method.
Set AzureOptions::account_name

But I am not able to establish the connectivity.
Where can I specify the endpoint URL?
